# ODOO Selection - Hide some option on certain conditions

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I have a customer_type selection field in xml file but i need to hide 2 out of 4 selections that depends on condition.

[image]

So far this is my code in python

res_partner.py

```
customer_type = fields.Selection([
        ('cash_customer','Cash Customer'),
        ('credit_customer','Credit Customer'),
        ('cash_customer_vendor','Cash Customer and Vendor'),
        ('credit_customer_vendor','Credit Customer and Vendor')],
        string="Customer Type" )
```

res_partner.xml

```
<field name="customer_type" 
       attrs="{'required': 
       [('customer_tick', '=', True)],
       'invisible': [('customer_tick', '!=', True)]}"/>
```

My condition is

```
vendor_state = 'vendor'
```

Answer (score 2):

Andrywin Maquinto

Instead of add the `key, value` in the field try to add with the method.

```
customer_type = fields.Selection(selection="_get_customer_type", string="Customer Type")

def _get_customer_type(self):
    if self: # your codnition to check
        return [('cash_customer', 'Cash Customer'), ('credit_customer', 'Credit Customer'),
                ('cash_customer_vendor', 'Cash Customer and Vendor'),
                ('credit_customer_vendor', 'Credit Customer and Vendor')]
    else:
        return [('cash_customer', 'Cash Customer'), ('credit_customer', 'Credit Customer')]
```

Comment: i already try this.
i did write on my condition self.vendor_state == 'vendor'
it doesnt return true

i tried printing self.vendor_state it returns false, it was supposedly 'vendor'

Comment: `self` is an empty recordset, you can't use field values.

Comment: hello Dipen, thanks for the answer. It worked fine for me but creates an issue with filter that it shows undefined in group by filter in some cases. do you have any solution for this isse? please let me know